# Php refresh page if file not found

Tags: php, redirect, header

My code works. It changes the lang value if the added value doesn't exist. However, it requires a refresh to take the change.

```
if(isset($_GET['lang']) && file_exists('lang/'. $_SESSION['lang'] . '.php')) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
} else {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en'; // default value
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['lang'])) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en'; // default value
}
include('lang/'. $_SESSION['lang'] . '.php');
```

With the above code, it does change lang back to en if other lang doesn't exist but, it shows the error file not exist, then after refreshing page works fine.
Is there a way to redirect or refresh page right after lang is set back to en ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may have an error in your logic.

```
if(isset($_GET['lang']) && file_exists('lang/'. $_GET['lang'] . '.php'))
```

The first if statement you posted checks if the SESSION['lang'] file exists. It appears as though it should check to see if the GET['lang'] file exists.

You can use the header function to move the page.

```
header("Location: http://yoursite.com/yourpage.php");
```

You could also limit the error reporting so it doesn't show the error that a file doesn't exist.

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: If i use Header, it stucks in a redirecting loop.. and crushes all website.
where do i write the error_reporting(0); ?
And is not just showing error, it tries to include a file which doesn't exist, and all page will end up with no text.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood your statement then. I think you may need to post more code. Also, I am modifying my answer because I think I see a bigger problem.

Comment: I am translating my pages using array variables.
And have them in files: en.php, al.php
Then include them in my page depending on which lang visitors choose.
If they write ?lang=ru
It will try to include ru.php which doesnt exist. and will show page without text at all, until a refresh of page.